# Linked list questions

Tags: c, linked-list, traversal

Hey so i am trying to create a linked list. The following code segment opens the file for reading, which then gets passed into a function to take the string break it down and place it into a node which is suppose to be placed into the list in an appropriate location.

```
    void print_list(struct vm_node  *root);
    int addNodeBottom(char *val, struct vm_node *head);
    struct stock_item* setupNode(char *line);
    int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
        struct vm vm;
        struct menu_item menu_items[NUM_MENU_ITEMS];
        struct vm_node *vmNode;
        vmNode = malloc(sizeof(struct vm_node));

        /* The UNUSED() function is designed to prevent warnings while your
         * code is only partially complete. Delete these 4 function calls once
         * you are using the data structures declared above in your own code */
        UNUSED(argc);
        UNUSED(argv);
        UNUSED(vm);
        UNUSED(menu_items);
        if (argc != 3) {
            printf("insuffcient arguments \n");
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }

        /*open stock file*/
        char* fileName = argv[1];
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen(fileName, "r+");
        char buf[256];
        vmNode->next = NULL;

        while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file) != NULL) {

            addNodeBottom(buf,vmNode);

        }

        print_list(vmNode);
        /* Test reason for reaching NULL. */
        if (feof(file)) /* if failure caused by end-of-file condition */
            puts("End of file reached");
        else if (ferror(file)) /* if failure caused by some other error      */
        {
            perror("fgets()");
            fprintf(stderr, "fgets() failed in file %s at line # %d\n", __FILE__,
                    __LINE__ - 9);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        fclose(file);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

the following function is how i have described the setupNode function.

```
    struct stock_item* setupNode(char *line) {

        struct stock_item *root;
        root = malloc(sizeof(struct stock_item));
        char *ptr;
        const char del[2] = "|";
        const char delm[2] = ".";
        char *prices;
        strcpy(root->id, strtok_r(line, del, &ptr)); // returns the ID and stores in in the root node.
        strcpy(root->name, strtok_r(NULL, del, &ptr)); // returns the description and stores it in the root node.
        strcpy(root->description, strtok_r(NULL, del, &ptr)); // returns the description and stores it in the root node.
        prices = strtok_r(NULL, del, &ptr); // returns a string of the price for vm_item.
        int dol = atoi(strtok(prices, delm));
        int cent = atoi(strtok(NULL, delm));
        root->price.dollars = dol;
        root->price.cents = cent;
        int quantity = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, del, &ptr)); // returns how many items are in stock.
        root->on_hand = quantity;
        return root;

    }
```

This is the addNode function

```
    int addNodeBottom(char *val, struct vm_node *head){
        //create new node

        struct vm_node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct vm_node));
        if(newNode == NULL){
            printf("%s", "Unable to allocate memory for new node\n");
            exit(-1);
        }

        newNode->data = setupNode(val);
        newNode->next = NULL;  // Change 1

        //check for first insertion
        if(head->next == NULL){
            head->data = newNode->data;
            head->next = newNode;
        }

        else
        {
            //else loop through the list and find the last
            //node, insert next to it
            struct vm_node *current = head;
            while (TRUE) { // Change 2
                if(current->next == NULL)
                {
                    current->next = newNode;
                    break; // Change 3
                }
                current = current->next;
            };
        }
        free(newNode);
        return 0;
    }
```

and the printList function

```
    void print_list(struct vm_node  *root) {
        while (root) {
            printf("%s ", root->data->id);
            root = root->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Here is the typeDefs

```
    #ifndef VM_TYPE
    #define VM_TYPE

    #define IDLEN 5
    #define NAMELEN 40
    #define DESCLEN 255
    #define NUMDENOMS 8
    #define UNUSED(var) (void)var
    #define COIN_COUNT 20
    #define DEFAULT_ONHAND 20

    /* Type definition for our boolean type */
    typedef enum truefalse
    {
        FALSE, TRUE
    } BOOLEAN;

    /* Each price will have a dollars and a cents component */
    struct price
    {
        unsigned dollars,cents;
    };

    /* The different denominations of coins available */
    enum denomination
    {
        FIVE_CENTS, TEN_CENTS, TWENTY_CENTS, FIFTY_CENTS, ONE_DOLLAR, 
        TWO_DOLLARS, FIVE_DOLLARS, TEN_DOLLARS
    };

    /* Each coin in the coins array will have a denomination (20 cents, 
     * 50 cents, etc) and a count - how many of that coin do we have on hand
     */
    struct coin
    {
        enum denomination denom;
        unsigned count;
    };

    /* The data structure that holds the data for each item of stock
     */
    struct stock_item
    {
        char id[IDLEN+1];
        char name[NAMELEN+1];
        char description[DESCLEN+1];
        struct price price;
        unsigned on_hand;
    };

    /* The data structure that holds a pointer to the stock_item data and a
     * pointer to the next node in the list
     */
    struct vm_node
    {
        struct stock_item * data;
        struct vm_node * next;
    };

    /* The head of the list - has a pointer to the rest of the list and a 
     * stores the length of the list 
     */
    struct vm_list
    {
        struct vm_node * head;
        unsigned length;
    };

    /* This is the head of our overall data structure. We have a pointer to 
     * the vending machine list as well as an array of coins. 
     */
    struct vm
    {
        struct vm_list * item_list;
        struct coin coins[NUMDENOMS];
        char * foodfile;
        char * coinsfile;
    };

    #endif
```

and the format of the text file that is being read in for parsing.

```
 I0001|Coke            |375 ml Can of coke                                         |3.50|50

 I0002|Pepsi           |375 ml Can of pepsi                                        |3.00|20

 I0003|Lemon Cheesecake|A delicious, 1/8 size slice of cheesecake                  |4.00|10

 I0004|Mars Bar        |A delicious 50 g Mars Bar chilled just the way you like it.|3.00|20

 I0005|Lemon Tart      |A delicious lemon butter tart with a pastry based          |3.75|12
```

The output when trying to print the list is complete garbage so any thoughts?

Comment: Just to pinpoint the errors, have you tried printing before putting it in the list to see what is printed? Maybe it's not a list issue but a reading issue

Comment: Also if you do not plan to edit the file open it using `fopen(filename,"r")`

Comment: When using the setupNode function feature i ensured that the information was being passed correctly by printing out the stock_item before returning it. So i know the information is being passed to a node correctly. I can show you the output if you would like of this step?

Comment: It is a requirement to add items to the file. Which is why i have r+

Comment: After completely reading your question I pinpointed the error. Look at my answer

Comment: I tried to be as explanatory as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because in `addNodeBottom` you make e.g. `current->next` point the new node you allocate, then you *free* the new node, so the pointer in `current->next` now point to unallocated memory.

Also, when setting up the first node (when `head->next` is `NULL`) then don't set the `next`  pointer of `head`, let it be `NULL`. Instead to distinguish between an empty list or not, check for a non-null `data` field:

```
if (head->data == NULL)
{
    // List is empty
}
else
{
    // List is not empty
}
```

Other tips: There's no need to allocate a new node until you actually add it to the list. And the loop to find the last node in the list can be simplified to this:

```
vm_node *current;
for (current = head; current->next != NULL; current = current->next)
{
    // Empty loop body
}
```

After the above loop `current` will be the last node in the list, and you can now allocate a new node.

---

If I would rewrite the `addNodeBottom` function (without modifying the function signature), it would look something like this (without any error handling):

```
int addNodeBottom(char *val, struct vm_node *head){
    //create new node

    stock_item *data = setupNode(val);

    if (head->data == NULL)
        head->data = data;
    else
    {
        vm_node *current;
        for (current = head; current->next != NULL; current = current->next)
            ;

        current->next = malloc(sizeof(*current->next));
        current->next->data = data;
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

***Note:*** You must set `vmNode->data = NULL` before calling the above function for the first time, not only `vmNode->next`.

Comment: Thanks, when i didnt free the memory i end up with the node being generated twice for the first node, but all other nodes are fine.

Comment: @JoshuaTheeuf That's because you do the assignment `head->next = newNode`. Then the next time the function is called, you dereference `head->next` which now point to unallocated memory (because you do `free(newNode)`) and you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is because you are creating a new Node, storing data in it and then deleting the new node using `free`.
I understand your logic as it is now in the list so you do not need it anymore. But that is not the issue. In the list you merely put a pointer that points to the new node you created. You do not copy the new node in the list. You only put a pointer that points to the allocated memory for the node you created. If you free that part of the memory then it no longer exists and that part can be overwritten by any other application or yours. So it ends up being garbage.

Comment: Um when i dont free the node i endup with a duplicate of the information in the headNode, and the 2nd node, and im unsure where this is actually happening.

Comment: Ok. First you must change the `head->next==NULL` to `head==NULL`. That is the proper way to check if a list is empty. Try that and let me know of the outcome

Comment: When i do this it ignores the headNode, and prints out every other node. So when just printing out the id's i get the following output: (null) I0001 I0002 I0003 I0004 I0005 
So i have no idea. If i change 'code current->next == NULL to current == next it appears to segfault.

Comment: Only change it in the addNode Method not everywhere